# If textbox contain a specific string do some function - javascript

Tags: javascript, string, textbox, contain

I am wondering how to search specific string in big textbox (which contains 200 words) so I can make function to color them.    Ex. In textbox there is a sentence "my dog is happy" and i want string "dog" to become red by button or sth else. Is it possible???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. But don't use a text box or text area, use a `div` with `contenteditable = "true"`:

```
<div id="editableDiv" class="editable" contenteditable="true">
    This is a sentence containing 'dog'.<br />
    You can edit the contents of this div.
</div>
<button id="highlightBtn">Highlight "dog"</button>
<script type="text/javascript">
   highlightBtn.onclick = function() {
         var elem = document.getElementById('editableDiv');
         elem.innerHTML = elem.innerHTML.replace(/dog/g, 
                            '<span class="redText">dog</span>');
   }
 </script>
```

And don't forget to create the classes `redText` and `editable` in your stylesheet:

```
.editable {
    padding: 5px;
    border: dashed 1px black;
}
.redText {
    color: red;
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ProgramFOX/UMMPh/